# Не работает ScrollView (kivy)

Tags: kivy, scrollview

Я изучаю kivy, хочу сделать прокручиваемый набор кнопок из kivymd, для этого использую MDScrollViewRefreshLayout (взял из [примера](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/Components-Refresh-Layout)). Но часть кнопок невидно, а то что видно не прокручивается. Хотелось бы увидеть максимально простой пример использования ScrollView, так что бы python код и разметка были раздельно. Я находил понятный для меня [пример](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py), но там не было отдельного файла разметки и я не смог понять как получить нужный мне результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main.py

```
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')    
Window.size = (351, 512)                     

Builder.load_file('dictionary.kv')

class Basic(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Basic, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.main = Factory.MainMenu()

    def build(self):
        return self.main

Basic().run()
```

dictionary.kv
:

```
MDScrollViewRefreshLayout:
    do_scroll_x: False
    size_hint_y: None
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 30
        spacing: 20
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {"top": -.6}
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 1_'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 2'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 3'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: "game 4"
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 1'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 2'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 3'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: "game 4"
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None

        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 1'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 2'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 3'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: "game 4"
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 1'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 2'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: 'game 3'
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
        MDTextButton:
            text: "game 4"
            heigh: dp(60)
            size_hint_y: None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением оказалась строчка `height: self.minimum_height` в `BoxLayout`. И при этом нужно указывать размер каждой кнопки `heigh: dp(60)`

Если у вас возникла проблема с ScrollView, проверьте следующее:

1. Что вы отключили автоматическую адаптацию высоты, у layoute который вы собираетесь скролить:  `size_hint_y: None`
2. Что у вас указана высота **виджитов** в вашем layoute: `heigh: dp(60)`
3. Установите высоту layoute который вы скролите на минимум: `height: self.minimum_height`
4. Убедитесь, что у вас есть что скролить, то есть что виджиты не помещаются на экран.
    :

   ```
   MDScrollViewRefreshLayout:
       BoxLayout:
           orientation: "vertical"
           size_hint_y: None             #отключение автоматической адаптации высоты
           height: self.minimum_height   #установить высоту layoute на минимум
           MDTextButton:
               text: 'game 1_'
               heigh: dp(60)             #высота виджита
   ```